# Filtering JavaPairRDD based on a JavaRDD in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm very new in Apache Spark. I need a Java solution for the problem below:

```
JavaPairRDD:        JavaRDD:           Desired Output:

1,USA               France             2,England
2,Engand            England            3,France
3,France
4,Italy
```

Edit:
Frankly, I have no idea about what I can try. Like I said, I'm very very newbie at spark. I just thought I can use a method something like instersection. But it requires another JavaPairRDD object. I think the filter method won't work for this problem. For example,

```
Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean> myFilter =
  new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(Tuple2<String, String> keyValue)
      {
        return ("some boolean expression");
      }
    };
myPairRDD.filter(myFilter);
```

I have no idea what kind of boolean expression I can write instead of "some boolean expression" in above function. Sorry for my English by the way.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three options:

- map `JavaRDD` to `JavaPairRDD` with arbitrary value, `join` and `map` to drop dummy values
- if number of unique values in `JavaRDD` is small, `collect` `distinct` values, convert to `Set`, `broadcast` and use it to `filter` `JavaPairRDD`
- convert both `RDDs` to `DataFrames` and use inner join followed by `drop` / `select`.

Comment: Actually, the first option was the first idea that comes to my mind. But I was very confused about joins. Your answer encouraged me and I solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: This pattern of `someRDD.map(x => (x, null)).doSomethingThatRequiresPairwiseRDD` is quite common in Spark source. This for example how `distinct` works.